# Storing tags without several trips to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tagging

This is what I normally do to store tags in a database:

```
   foreach ($tags as $tag)
   {
      if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES ('$tag')") === false)
      {
         $queries_ok[] = false;   # I'm using this because I have autocommit set to false, i.e. mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);
      }      
   }
```

However this involves connecting to the database several times, so if you have 10 tags, it involves connecting 10 times, is there another, simplier, faster way of doing this?

Comment: "Another": Yes. See Marc B, mfonda, etc. "Simpler": Probably not. "Faster": Probably, but just how much faster may be negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has an 'extended insert' syntax, which looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), etc...
```

The only drawback is that this format is not supported by prepared statements, so you have to build the query yourself, which means taking the usual steps to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: I am no PHP expert, but wouldn't it be possible to dynamically build the SQL statement with `len(tags) * '(?)'` and add the parameters the safe way? Manually sanitizing input seems like risky business to me…

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode: that general idea is a great way to go :). In PHP you'll need to use `str_repeat` function.

Comment: Placeholders are a single-value type thing. All the repeated fieldsets would try to get squished into the first table field specified in the fields part of the insert query, leaving b/c blank. Think of them as a glorified `printf()` type format-string.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, (I don't do this for a job, nor am I looking to release any site into the wild, so don't be scared),..um... I don't really use prepared statements, I use filter_var (etc) when I get user input then/along with regex to allow only certain characters and sometimes html_purifier if HTML is expected. I then use mysqli_real_escape_string on the input. Should I be using prepared statements each time?

Comment: Prepared statements do save you the trouble of having to manually building query strings and doing all the SQL-injection avoidance stuff, but they don't work in all situations. This is one of them.

Comment: I choose this because I don't use prepared statements, and its a bit late to change now.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using prepared statements. Psuedocode, because I don't remember PHP's exact functions:

```
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tag(name) VALUES (?)');
$st->bindParam(1, $tag);
foreach ($tags as $tag)
  $st->exec();
```

While you are still hitting the DB per call, the query itself is not parsed on each `exec()` and you get the added benefit of safe parameter checking.

Comment: +1 for Prepared Statements, and anything to help with preventing SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows with one insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES ('tag1'), ('tag2'), ('tag3'), ...
```

Comment: Say I dont know how many tags there are in the array? How would you do it then?

Comment: Build this query with code, using a `foreach` type loop for the content that comes after "VALUES". See the answer by Marc B, re: SQL Injection.

Comment: Use `implode()` or a loop to build the string. Better yet is to build a string with `?`'s, then use prepared statements to execute using the tag array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the select/union alternatieve to be fairly generic and have used it lots of times on systmes where the extended insert wasn't available :

something  (I have no databases on this host..) like this :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (a,b,c)
SELECT 1, 2, 3 
union 
SELECT 4, 5, 6
union 
SELECT 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what mfonda said you can do a

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c)
SELECT 1,2,3
UNION 
SELECT 4,5,6
UNION
SELECT 7,8,9;
```

This is the old school way, pre SQL-92 standard. This is how I was taught by all the old timers.